# Big Commerce : How to send order details to a custom system in real time?

Tags: bigcommerce

This question particularly relates to **Big Commerce**.
I wish to pass **Order data**, *real time*, to a custom system, maybe using an API or whatever appropriate. Also, update Inventory on Big Commerce by calling an API from my custom system.

Fact is, I am trying to maintain two systems. One is already on Big Commerce, the other is a custom system. I wish the stocks to be in sync in both systems.
Q1 - is it possible in the first place ?
Q2 - If yes, could you please guide me.

Thanks,
Saket

Answer (score 0):

You can get order detail in real time by using [Webhooks](https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api/webhooks-getting-started).

OR you can make API calls from your custom system at frequent intervals to get list of orders([Orders API](https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api/stores/v2/orders#list-orders))